# filter on django-import-export

Tags: django, django-models, django-import-export

I want to create csv file form my model send a dictionary of Queries (  filter exclude ) to [django-import-export](https://github.com/bmihelac/django-import-export) and return data from my model.

using flowing code i have all of model fields but i need to filter them with a query.

```
from import_export import resources
from finance.models import Price

class ExportData(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Price
```

Comment: What do you exactly want to filter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pass `queryset` to export method:

```
queryset = Price.objects.exclude(...)
data = ExportData().export(queryset)
data.csv
```

Comment: I just noticed by logging the SQL queries django actually makes, this apparently evaluates the queryset and then makes queryset.count() infividual SQL queries to generate the CSV. Not cool

Comment: I followed the instructions from this answer and now I get this error: `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'before_export'`. It make no sense to me since the exceptions raises at the export method of import_export.resources.Resource instead of the django.models.query.QuerySet class. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

To filter only Exported file and not the actual list in the Admin screen you can overwrite the `get_export_queryset` method

```
from import_export import resources
from import_export.admin import ImportExportMixin

class ProductAdmin(ImportExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = ProductResource

    # Override of ImportExportMixin.get_export_queryset
    # Filter export to exclude Products where is_active is false
    def get_export_queryset(self, request):
            return Product.objects.filter(is_active=True)
```

Comment: Can't find this in the docs https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html

Comment: @ecairol.@Omida Raha. How would I do it if incase my filter is to come from a dropdown selection???

Comment: "get_export_queryset" worked perfectly in my case, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

You can override the `export` method of `resources.ModelResource` in your `admin.py` file, to apply your filter on admin:

```
from import_export import resources
from finance.models import Price

class ExportData(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Price

    def export(self, queryset=None, *args, **kwargs):
        # For example only export objects with ids in 1, 2, 3 and 4
        queryset = queryset and queryset.filter(id__in=[1, 2, 3, 4])
        return super(ExportData, self).export(queryset, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: @Omida Raha. How would I do it if incase my filter is to come from a dropdown selection???

Answer (score 0):

You can just modify a export method of ModelResource class.

```
from import_export import resources
from finance.models import Price

class ExportData(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Price
    
    def export(self, queryset = None, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = queryset.exclude(id = 5)
        return super().export(queryset, *args, **kwargs)
```